# How to take specifig column from relation ship in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am getting Consignment model which belongsTo Product type model so when i try to access name of product type i use this query

```
 $consignment->product_types->name
```

But checked that this queries mean

```
select* from product_types
```

In my projectti am using this method many places which is now creating issue. Is there any method i can just take specific columns?

Comment: What is the result of `$consignment->product_types->name`? What do you mean by creating issue?

Comment: Can you add code samples of what you have tried...Model of both Consignment and Product.

Answer (score 1):

### You may specify which relationships should be eager loaded using the [**with**] method:

```
    $companies = Company::select('id', 'name', 'phone')
            ->with('customers:id,company_id,name')
            ->get();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($companies->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can restrict it in your query builder:

```
Consignment::with(['product_types' => function ($query) {
    $query->select("id", "consignment_id", "name");
}])->get();
```